# Where do I access settings to change the layout and fields of the edit/create new contact dialogue in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have Outlook 2016 installed on 2 different computers.

On the first computer, if I try to create or edit a contact, the dialogue looks like this:
[image]

On the second computer, it looks like this:
[image]

The differences being:

- The alignment of the phone fields.
- The address field is a raw text field in the first one and you can
  click the `Business...` button to bring up the `Check Address`
  dialogue, while on the second computer, it is broken up into the
  address elements.

Where can I access the settings to customize these fields to switch the Address fields between raw text and address element fields and to change the layout of the phone number fields?